# How do I gather statistics about function calls occurring in a Postgres schema?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I am looking for a way to efficiently gather statistics that would tell me how many times each function gets called in a given period of time.

By efficient, I mean the stat collector should use as few disk I/O operations as possible.

It would be nice if I can also track some more stats like the return time however this is not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's already built-in.

Check out the system view `pg_stat_user_functions`
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-USER-FUNCTIONS-VIEW

Note that you need to enable that in your `postgresql.conf`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-SETUP

To reset the collected statistics, use `pg_stat_reset()`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCTIONS

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. I'll wait for sometime to let some more answers come in.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the features horse mentioned, there's also:

- [`pg_stat_statements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html)
- [`pg_stat_plans`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans), an enhanced version of `pg_stat_statements`
- [`pgbadger`](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger), a log analysis tool
- [`pgtop`](http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org/), a real time activity monitor

I consider both `pgbadger` and `pg_stat_statements` essential components of any production PostgreSQL install.